# "string temp(s);" where "s" is string

Tags: c++, string, syntax, parameter-passing, declaration

```
void printAllPermutations(string s) 
{ 

   // Sorting String 
   string temp(s); 
   sort(temp.begin(), temp.end()); 

   // Print first permutation 
   cout << temp << endl; 

   // Finding the total permutations 
   int total = calculateTotal(temp, temp.length()); 
   for (int i = 1; i < total; i++)  
   { 
       nextPermutation(temp); 
   } 
} 

int main()  
{ 
   string s = "AAB"; 
   printAllPermutations(s); 
}
```

string 's' is a formal parameter of the function printAllPermutations().
My doubt is that :
How is "string temp(s);" written when 's' is also a string and 'temp' is the new string that needs to be created?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about.  Please clarify your question. `s` is a `std::string`, and `temp` is a `std::string` that is copy-constructed from `s`.  `std::string` has a copy constructor that will copy the data from `s` to `temp`. Same as with `s` in `main()` being copied into `s` in `printAllPermutations()`

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
string temp(s);
```

is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) of `temp`. The compiler will find the best matching constructor overload, which will be the copy-constructor for `string`. That means you really copy-construct `temp` from `s`, and it's equivalent to

```
string temp = s;
```

Which means that `temp` will be a copy of `s`.

---

Considering that the `printAllPermutations` function takes the argument `s` by value, you don't really need the `temp` variable, you could work on `s` directly, since it will in turn be a copy of the string you used in the call to `printAllPermutations`.

By using `temp` you initially have three copies of the string: The original string in the `main` function used for the `printAllPermutations` call; The copy in `s`; And the copy in `temp`.

Actually you don't need the object `s` in the `main` function either, you could pass the literal string `"AAB"` directly in the function call:

```
printAllPermutations("AAB");
```